How to get locale fallback in sequence (or API)?
How to get locale fallback in sequence? For example, for a locale (language tag)
 a-b-c-d

Normally it's fallback locales in sequence are:
a-b-c-d
a-b-c
a-b
a
ROOT

But it is not always true. e.g.,
zh-SG

Its fallback locales are:
zh-SG
zh-Hans
zh
ROOT

Is there a standard way (API) for this?

Have you seen this?

Thanks for info.
